# Cannot figure out how to get THIS running total

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

This question may have been asked already, however I'm not sure how to search for this specific problem.

What I'm trying to do is get a total count of "unclaimed" services.

An "unclaimed" service is a service that has a balance of greater than zero and no associated "claim" record.

```
- @Claimed -
IF ISNULL({CLAIM.ID}) AND SUM({@Balance}) > 0 THEN
    1 //"Unclaimed"
ELSE
    0 //"Claimed"
```

Balance is calculated by the SUM of each revenue line

```
 - @Balance -
 {REVENUE} - {PAYMENT} + {TRANSFER} - {ADJUST}
```

The @Claimed formula is on the group 1 footer and the @Balance formula is within the details. There can be multiple revenue lines, and the sum of each @Balance line is the remaining balance of that service.

The @Claimed formula works as expected - however I need to be able to get a SUM of all the "unclaimed" records (@Claimed) - but you cannot get a Running Total of a Running Total. So I would really appreciate some fresh eyes on the issue. I'm sure I'm attacking this the wrong way.

EDIT: More information

The report layout is as follows:

```
Main Service Details
GH1a | Service Date   - Service ID   - Etc
GH1b | {SERVICE.DATE} - {SERVICE.ID} - {ETC}

Service Revenue Line Details 
GH1c | Revenue   - Payment      - Transfer   - Adjustment   - Balance
D    | {REVENUE} - {PAYMENT}    - {TRANSFER} - {ADJUSTMENT} - {@Balance}

Service Revenue Totals
GF1b |  Claimed    - Revenue      - Payments      - Final Balance
GF1c |  {@Claimed} - RT {REVENUE} - RT {PAYMENTS} - RT of {@Balance}

ALL Services Revenue Totals
RFa  | Total Unclaimed - Total Revenue - Total Payments  - Total Balance
RFb  | ???             - RT            - RT              - RT of {@Balance} no reset
```

RT = Running Total Fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by just adding the values as the value repeats. Something like below.

```
Shared numbervar Total;

Total:=Total+@claimed;
Total;
```

This will make sure value is added and result is displayed....

Place the formula in group footers.

Now create one more formula display and place it in report footer

```
Shared numbervar Total;
Total
```

Comment: Thank you! This appears to be working. I was on this path earlier but did not have the wherewithal to complete it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try create a running total field:

```
Running total name = UnclaimedCount
Field to summarize = @Claimed
Type of summary = sum
Evalute = on change of group 1
Reset = never
```

Remember to grant that fields {REVENUE}, {PAYMENT}, {TRANSFER}, {ADJUST} are not null.

EDIT:: if @Claimed is a running total field (#Claimed), change it to be an usual formula.

Comment: I cannot simply create a running total on `@Claimed` because it contains a running total [ sum(@Balance) ]. This is where my problem is.

Comment: ok, i dont understand why @Balance would be a running total field instead of a regular formula, but probably you have a good reason for that. anyways, Siva gave you a solution. i dont like shared variables, but sometimes it is the way.

Comment: @Balance is not a running total - but I need the running total of balance across all detail lines for a @Claim comparison - `if isnull({CLAIM.OID}) and {#ServiceBalance} > 0 then
   1
else
   0`